# How to return the rowcount of a dynamic sql query in SP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to return the rowcount of a dynamic sql query using linq similar to mentioned here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

I'm using dynamic sql to create the where clause and to implement paging on the result set,  The rowcount I want to return is the total number of records that meet the where condition.

My SQL that is causing me problems:

```
-- get row count


SET @SQL = '@TotalRowCount = SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalRowCount'
                SET @SQL = @SQL + @WHERE

                IF (LEN(@SUBWHERE) > 0)
                BEGIN
                SET @SQL = @SQL + @SUBWHERE
                END

                SET @SQL = @SQL + ')) '


                exec sp_executesql @SQL



                END
```

(I need this to be the output param @TotalRowCount in the param list here):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[_tournament_GetTournamentsByConveners]
(

    @LastName varchar(100)   = null ,

    @Username varchar(256)   = null ,

    @Email varchar(100)   = null ,

    @IsWildcard bit = null,

    @PageIndex int ,

    @PageSize int,

    @TotalRowCount int output 
)
AS
```

Comment: I'm missing the "LINQ-bit". If there is an SP, just invoke it? (LINQ2SQL will generate the stub which supports `out` values.)

Comment: When using LINQ I'm getting an exception that I must declare the scalar value @TotalRowCount

Comment: I don't understand your question completely but maybe it should be: `SELECT @TotalRowCount = COUNT(*) as TotalRowCount ...` btw, where is your FROM part? I only see there WHERE part. Also, perhaps you are missing some spaces in your query. Make sure, your @subwhere contains two opening brackets more than it does closing brackets.

Comment: That is a problem with the SP -- nothing to do with LINQ :-) Try running it from SQL Management Studio, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.

The scope of the @TotalRowCount in the dynamic SQL is different to the scope of @TotalRowCount declared in the stored procedure. That is, the dynamic SQL has it's own scope.

If you insist on using dynamic SQL, do this to add the total rows to the record set that is returned

```
SELECT col1, col2,
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalRows
FROM ...
```

Otherwise we only have partial code to offer any suggestions for improvement. You appear to have LINQ to call stored procs with execute dynamic SQL. This is too convoluted.

Comment: thank you gbn. i was following the same pattern here calling stored procedure from linq which is handling paging on sql level.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare output parameters with `sp_executesql`. So to get your result alter the code as shown below.

Always be careful when concatenating SQL code like this as it is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)

SET @SQL = N'SELECT @TotalRowCount = COUNT(*) as TotalRowCount'
SET @SQL = @SQL + @WHERE

IF (LEN(@SUBWHERE) > 0)
  BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @SUBWHERE
  END

SET @SQL = @SQL + N')) '

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@TotalRowCount int output', @TotalRowCount output
```

you can also express this more compact as:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)

SET @SQL = N'SELECT @TotalRowCount = COUNT(*) as TotalRowCount' + @WHERE + ISNULL(@SUBWHERE, N'') + N'))'

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@TotalRowCount int output', @TotalRowCount output
```